# how to fix invalid-zero length error?

Tags: database, database-restore

I create a backup from my database by this code:

```
    "USE DBFP; " +
    "BACKUP DATABASE DBFP " +
    "TO DISK = '" + strFileName + "'";
```

but when i want to restore this backup by this code:

```
 "RESTORE DATABASE DBFP FROM DISK = '" + strFileName+"'"
```

this error will apear:

```
Invalid zero-length device name!
```

Comment: What’s the value of `strFileName` when you try to restore?

Comment: What database ? Microsoft SQL-Server, Sybase, MySQL  ?

Comment: strFileName come from a file dialog!its sql server database